# Printer driver which number repersent B5 pages in PCL

Tags: printers, printer-control-language

i want program a printer driver.use the pcl for my driver.PCL has one command represent the page types.in PCL number **9** represent **A4**.i want to know which **number** represent **B5** in PCL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this reference from HP, International B5 is represented by 100. However, it also says that A4 is represented by 26.

http://h20565.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-bpl13205

Where did you read that 9 represents A4?